# How to run XMPP server with GCM?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the `XMPP` server as described in the google api.
The `main` function that was written is sending a downstream message. I used `while(true)` loop to keep the server running.
I was wondering what is the best practice for keeping the server app awake and process messages.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long senderId = ***; // your GCM sender id
    final String password = "***";

    SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

    ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);

    while(true){}
}
```

Comment: I feel that keeping server awake will in general not be an issue as long as you follow the guidelines and examples from the [**officialDoc**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html). I see more problems occurring in the client side (devices) usually.